# Histogram of integer without looping

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I was wandering if there is any STL algorithm which produces the same result of the following code:

```c++
std::vector<int> data;
std::vector<int> counter(N); //I know in advance that all values in data
                             //are between 0 and N-1

for(int i=0; i<data.size(); ++i)
    counter[data[i]]++;
```

This code simply outputs the histogram of my integer data, with pre-defined bin size equal to one.

I know that I should avoid loops as much as I could, as the equivalents with STL algorithms are much better optimized than what the majority of C++ programmer may come up with.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance, Giuseppe

Comment: Shouldn't that be `counter[data[...`?

Comment: Yes, it should, thank you. Corrected...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can certainly at least clean up the loop a bit:

```
for (auto i : data) 
    ++count[i];
```

You *could* (for example) use `std::for_each` instead:

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&count](int i) { ++count[i]; });
```

...but that doesn't really look like much (if any) of an improvement to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a more efficient way of doing this. You're right about avoiding loops and preferring STL in most cases, but this only applies to bigger, and overly-complicated loops which are harder to write and maintain, therefore likely to be not optimal.

Looking at the problem at an assembly level, the only way to compute this problem is exactly the way you have it in your example. Since C/C++ loops translate to assembly very efficiently with zero unnecessary overhead, this leaves me believing that no STL function could preform this faster than your algorithm.

There is one STL function called [count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/), but the complexity of it is linear ( O(n) ), and so as your solution's.

If you really want to squeeze out the maximum of every CPU-cycle, then consider using C-style arrays, and a separate counter variable. The overhead introduced by vectors is barely even measurable, but if any, that's the only opportunity I see for optimization here. Not that I would suggest it, but I'm afraid that's the only way you can get a hair more speed out of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, in order to count the occurrences of elements in a vector, each element would have to be "visited" at least once, there's no avoiding it.

A simple loop like this is already the most efficient. You can try to unroll it, but that's probably the best you can do. STL or not, I doubt if there's a better algorithm.

Comment: Hi! True, you have to visit all element of the vector data. I was thinking about optimizations similar to the ones that are implemented in LAPAK of EIGEN. For example, their algoritm to compute the matrix multiplication is much faster than what you would obtain with normal loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for_each and one lambda function. Check this example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
const int N = 10;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    std::vector<int> counter(N);
    std::vector<int> data(N);

    generate(data.begin(),data.end(),[]{return rand()%N;});

    for (int i = 0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;

    cout<<endl;

    for_each(data.begin(),data.end(),[&counter](int i){++counter[i];});

    for (int i = 0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<counter[i]<<endl;
}
```